# Ajuda entre duas campanhas Adwords distintas

Tags: automatização, ad

Tenho duas lojas online com duas contas adwords distintas.
Pretendia fazer uma campanha de Adwords em que as duas lojas online estivessem sempre a aparecer no topo (até aqui fácil) e arranjar uma forma que de hora a hora o anuncio que aparece em 1o lugar e 2o lugar, troquem de lugar.

Tentei fazer através de regras automatizadas mas não obtive o resultado que procurava.